# Eclipse Google Cloud plugin Unable to start DevAppServer: InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make static java.net.URLStreamHandler

Tags: eclipse, plugins, local

Trying to get a basic setup working to run the local Google App Engine running in Eclipse using the Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse, but I keep getting the error below when starting the server using the Run As -> App Engine option.

I believe my environment is good because I am able to run the test application with a local app server from the command line using the java_dev_appserver command, so the problem seems specific to the Eclipse environment.

```
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:383)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:315)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:385)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:59)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:259)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:250)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:368)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make static java.net.URLStreamHandler java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(java.lang.String) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @49c43f4e
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory.<clinit>(StreamHandlerFactory.java:53)
    ... 12 more
```

I started from a clean Windows 11 machine, installed Google Cloud SDK, added the app-engine-java component, configured a project, tested by deploying to the cloud with the CLI, installed Eclipse, added the Google Tools for Eclipse plugin, created a sample project using the Google plugin Create Project -> Google App Engine Standard project, and tried to run it.

This is probably very simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What version of Java? The most recent Java releases, especially Java 17 are much stricter about not allowing code to mess about with JDK internals.

Comment: Good question. I was using the default v17 JRE. I reinstalled with an older JRE (v11) and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was happening with JRE v17 that installs by default with Eclipse 2021-12. Installing Eclipse with JRE v11 solved the problem. Thanks to greg-449 for putting me on the right track.

Comment: Hi @charles, I was already on Java v11 and also downgraded to java v8 but doesn't seems a resolution for me! I posted details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73786785/3327951. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I hit this problem when upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17, (and so wasn't interested in downgrading back to Java 11).  I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading some of my other dependencies.  Specifically, going to

```
appengine-gradle-plugin:2.4.5
spring-test:6.0.10
```

solved the problem.  I'll leave which one of these was the critical change as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the JVM to jdk-11.0.13 solved this problem for me as well.

Since I didn't un-install JRE v17, I had to change my eclipse.ini file to point to JDK 11, then update the Eclipse workspace settings for installed JRE's to include JDK 11 and update my workspace properties to use that version by default instead of the JRE 17. I also updated the JDK compliance settings to be JDK 11 instead of 17 and disabled the "release" setting that wanted to still use 17.

Thanks for this post.  I had been working on this problem for several days upgrade/downgrading libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am already on java version 11 and after looking here and there, I have downgraded from 11 to 8 but still facing same issue with eclipse plugin.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create a DevAppServer
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:378)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:310)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:384)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:58)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:363)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make static java.net.URLStreamHandler java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(java.lang.String) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @133e16fd
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory.<clinit>(StreamHandlerFactory.java:52)
    ... 12 more
```

Any suggestion, What can be the issue?